# Position and width of a black transparent filter (CSS, bootstrap 4)

Tags: html, css, position, bootstrap-4

I use the newest version of bootstrap and I have some trouble with the CSS as I'm not used to it (by that I mean not used to bootstrap : at all).

I want to put a black filter on my images (those to the right in the "Qui suis-je" section) like I did on my slider (where it works very well !). But... There is a shift (maybe cause of the col classes). I want to keep the same padding, so if I put a "padding : 0" to the parent (class sec-1-2) it becomes too big.

Could someone help me please ?

here is my website (currently under construction as you will see) : [blog.amelie-mathieu.fr](http://blog.amelie-mathieu.fr), and the [screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFBt4.png)  . Even if you'll be able to see the code on the brower console, here is the concerned code below.

Thank you very much !

```css
.sect-1-2 {
    height: 100%;
}

.sect-1-2 img {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
 }

.play img {
    width: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 15%;
}

.play {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sect-1-2 col-lg-6 col-md-12">
         <div class="transparent-bg2"></div>
         <div class="play"><img src="images/play.png"/></div>
         <div><img src="images/Thumbnail-CV-vidéo-Janvier-2018.png" class="img-fluid"/></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: *Forgot to say "Hello", thank you by advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `absolute` positioning of `.transparent-bg2` takes it out of the document flow, thus ignoring the padding of the parent element. To account for this, one solution would be to use [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to set the width of the absolute positioned element to 100% - 30px(the combined width of the padding on the parent element):

```
.transparent-bg2 {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    position:absolute;
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
    width:calc(100% - 30px); /* subtract parent element padding from width */
    height:100%;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: Ohh thank you very much it works ! I didn't know such a property existed :o thanks again :)